# C# WSDL API как обратиться к массиву?

Tags: c#, .net, wsdl

```
ServiceReference2.MedicataMOV2PortClient client = new ServiceReference2.MedicataMOV2PortClient();
var results = client.CancelRx(new ServiceReference2.CancelRxRequest()
{
    PracticeLocation = new ServiceReference2.PracticeLocationType()
    {
        Identification = new ServiceReference2.FacilityID()
        {
            ID = "101",
            MedicareNumber = "101",
            Ogrn = "101"
        },
        BusinessName = "Городская клиническая больница №1. Поликлиника №1",
    }
}
```

Как к методам обращаться все понятно, по такому принципу, а вот как обратиться к массиву, не знаю, может кто помочь?

```
 public partial class DrugCoded : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {
    
    private object[] itemsField;
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("CompositeProductCode", typeof(DrugProductCodeWithDoseText), Order=0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("IndividualManufactured", typeof(BooleanCode), Order=0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ProductClarifyingFreeText", typeof(string), Order=0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ProductCode", typeof(DrugProductCodeWithText), Order=0)]
    public object[] Items {
        get {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemsField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Items");
        }
    }
```

Как вызвать CompositeProductCode?

Comment: К массиву чего? В приведенном коде нет массивов. Или вы имеете в виду спрятанный тип в `var`? Замените его в таком случае на явный тип. Потом, к массиву обращаются с чтобы получить какой-то результат, какой результат вы хотите получить?

Comment: @aepot я добавил, в вопрос код, можете подсказать?

Comment: _Как вызвать CompositeProductCode?_ - зачем, для чего вам это? Какой результат вы хотите получить? Как бы вы обращались к этому свойству, если был бы не массив, а один элемент?

Comment: <DrugCoded>
      <ProductCode>
       <Code>GD049</Code>
       <Qualifier>GenericDrug</Qualifier>
       <Text>, капсулы, 500 мг</Text>
      </ProductCode>
     </DrugCoded>
Мне нужно в ProductCode передать Code,qualiier и text

Comment: Вы можете словами написать, какую задачу вы решаете? Я не знаю, как этот вопрос еще переформулировать. Что вы хотите получить в итоге?

Comment: _Мне нужно в ProductCode передать Code,qualiier и text_ окей, какому именно элементу массива? Первому, последнему, какому-то в середине? Какому? Или всем?

Comment: Как я понимаю я создаю этот элемент массива

Comment: Я создаю запрос и вношу в него значения, когда дело касалось только методов, все было хорошо, но тут появился массив и все сломалось у меня

Comment: `Items = new object[4];` `Items[0] = new DrugProductCodeWithDoseText(...);`

Comment: А если бы я вам дал ссылку на WSDL, вы могли бы посмотреть?

Comment: Я работаю с другими инструментами, так что вряд-ли. Но в комментариях вы добавили много полезного, и лучше перенесите в вопрос то, что из этого считаете важным.

Comment: Items = new object[4]; Items[0] = new DrugProductCodeWithDoseText(...);
Так нельзя сделать в моем методе(

Comment: _Как вызвать CompositeProductCode?_ - никак. Вызвать можно метод. А тип нужно создать.

Comment: Почему в вопросы вы упоминаете `CompositeProductCode`, а в комментариях говорите о `ProductCode`. Не скачите с одного на другое, остановитесь на чём-то одном.

Comment: _Так нельзя сделать в моем методе_ - в программировании нет понятия "нельзя". Есть конкретная ошибка с чётким описанием. Приведите её.

Comment: Давайте ваш WSDL

Comment: https://api-test.e-rx31.ru/ws/medicata-mo-v2.wsdl

Comment: А вот код для вашего удобства:

Comment: ServiceReference2.MedicataMOV2PortClient client = new ServiceReference2.MedicataMOV2PortClient();
var results = client.CancelRx(new ServiceReference2.CancelRxRequest()
            {PrescribedMedication = new ServiceReference2.RxMedication()
                { ... }});

Comment: На месте пропуска мне и надо объявить значения этого массива

Answer (score 0):

Вся проблема, как я выяснил в том, что MS Studio неправильно импортировал WSDL. И теперь нужна ручная доработка импорта, а как сделать, я понятия не имею